# Given two sequences of positive numbers with $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{x_n}{y_n}$ and $\sum_{n\ge1}y_n$ convergent, is $\sum_{n\ge1}\sqrt{x_n}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider two sequences of **positive numbers** $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$. Suppose that the series

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{x_n}{y_n}$$

and the series

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} y_n$$

are both convergent. Is the series

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} \sqrt{x_n}$$

also convergent?

This is what I tried:

We know that the series:

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{x_n}{y_n} \hspace{4cm} \sum_{n \ge 1} y_n$$

are both convergent. By the $n^{th}$ Term Test, we can conclude that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} = 0$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = 0$$

Now, since we know that the series $\sum_{n \to \infty} y_n$ is convergent **and** that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n}{y_n} = 0 \in [0, \infty) \cup \{\infty \}$$

we can conclude by the Second Comparison Test that the series

$$\sum_{n \to \infty} x_n$$

is convergent.

Now, using the $n^{th}$ Term Test again, we get that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$$

But this is about as far as I got. I don't really see how to draw any conclusion about the series $\sum_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{x_n}$. I don't know how to take into consideration that square root.

Comment: $\sqrt {x_n} =\sqrt {\frac  {x_n} {y_n}} \sqrt {y_n}$. Apply Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$\sqrt{x_n}\leqslant\frac12\left(\frac{x_n}{y_n}+y_n\right).$$

Comment: I see. I can apply the First Comparison Test on that inequality and then get that the series is convergent, right? Is what I did above completely useless? I don't see that it helps in any kind of way.

Comment: @user1502: Right. And I often continue the attempts given, when I can (and it isn't done by someone else). This time, I see no way.

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy–Schwarz inequality we have

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} \sqrt{x_n}=\sum_{n\ge1}\left(\frac{ \sqrt{x_n} }{ \sqrt{y_n}}\cdot \sqrt{y_n}\right)\le \left(\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{x_n}{y_n}\right)^2 \cdot \left(\sum_{n\ge1}y_n\right)^2 $$